# LDAP Query via Windows CMD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Everywhere I find solutions for how a LDAP Query has to look like in Windows CMD. For instance:

> Example for a LDAP Query in commandline-programm:
>   *ldapsearch -h ldap.acme.com -p 389 -s sub -D "cn=Directory Manager,o=acme" -W -b "ou=personen,o=acme" "(&(mail=joe*)(c=germany))" mail*

It is not a problem for me to adjust such a query to my needs, but none of the common help pages tells you how to make the ldap commands work. Everytime I am trying to execute a ldap command, comandline only response that the command is not known. 
Please tell what I have to download or where I have to navigate to make this command work.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered Installing the OpenLDAP client?

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can give me a link where I can download it for windows. I´ve tried 3 different installers now and the only one which seems to be the right one wants that I enter a registration key which I get via mail after I send a screenshot of the registration step of the installer to a certain mail-address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ldapsearch.exe is a tool that was included with Windows 2000, it isn't used anymore, and was superseded by [dsquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952(v=ws.11).aspx) in Server 2003. However if you are querying Active Directory, you should just use the [Active Directory PowerShell Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) instead, which is included with the [Remote Server Admin Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887).

Comment: No, I have a ldap query, I need to run the query to see the results.  It is in the ldap query format.  I need to copy and paste it and see what it returns.  Your answer does not help me.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use `dsquery`  so I ended up running Ubuntu in Docker and installing `ldap-utils` to use `ldapsearch` -.-